# KERNELCONFIG while building toolchain using crosstool-ng

Tags: glibc, toolchain, crosstool-ng, linux-toolchain

I am trying to update our cross compiler toolchain from crosstool to crosstool-ng. We are using an old kernel and build machine. I could install and configure crosstool-ng-1.0.0 on the server and build the toolchain. 
One difference that I have noticed between the output of crosstool and crosstool-ng is that the crosstool-ng is missing some of library under output folder. For example libcrypt.a, libdl.a, libnss_dns.so, libpthread.so and so on.

I have noticed that while building with crosstool we are setting KERNELCONFIG to a specific kernel configuration file. In that configuration file we have configurations like:

`CONFIG_CRYPTO=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_HMAC=ycryp
CONFIG_CRYPTO_NULL=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_MD4=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_MD5=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA1=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA256=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA512=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_DES=y`

Is this the reason that libraries like libcrypt are missing. In that case is there a way to set KERNELCONFIG in crosstool-ng for example as a build parameter?

Answer (score 1):

All the libraries you mention are part of glibc, and the glibc build does not depend on the kernel configuration at all. You should check if you have enabled building glibc at all.